# RStudio doens't seem to find rsession, how to set the path to rsession fixed?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a problem with RStudio. My environment is the following: We work on win 7 personal computers and have a network drive where most software is on installed. And we have administrator rights.

The newest version of R is installed and works fine after I adjust the workspace and the library path to H:\ instead of \networkdrive\code\codename. (I had a problem with installing some packages).

There were no problems with installing Rstudio. However for the first time launched it takes some time to start and it doens't show the script editor. When I try to open a (new) script it freezes and after a while it says the Rstudio R session take to long to respond. The next time that I want to start Rstudio it gives me an empty Rstudio.

The logs (at the end of the pos give a clear description of what the problem can be . It tries three times to start and Rsession from Rstudio but it searches after the wrong path. For example my part of the company network drive is //company/code/hm0226 but Rstudio changes this everytime it searches for Rsession.  Ofcourse it cannot find it.

Like in the library path i want to change it to H:\path\Rsession.exe but I don't know how. Could someone tell me how of knows a kind of solution for this problem? Or does it has to do with the firewall although we disabled simantec and tried but to no resolve?

```
Nov 2017 09:15:51 [rsession-home] ERROR system error 67 (The network name cannot be found) [path=//drive/code/hm1049]; OCCURRED AT: bool rstudio::core::FilePath::exists() const C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\FilePath.cpp:325; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::core::FilePath::exists() const C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\FilePath.cpp:325
23
Nov 2017 09:16:23 [rsession-home] ERROR system error 67 (The network name cannot be found) [path=//drive/code/hm1165]; OCCURRED AT: bool rstudio::core::FilePath::exists() const C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\FilePath.cpp:325; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::core::FilePath::exists() const C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\FilePath.cpp:325
23
Nov 2017 09:16:23 [rsession-home] ERROR system error 67 (The network name cannot be found) [path=//drive/code/hm1166]; OCCURRED AT: bool rstudio::core::FilePath::exists() const C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\FilePath.cpp:325; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::core::FilePath::exists() const C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\FilePath.cpp:325
23
Nov 2017 09:17:12 [rsession-home] WARNING Abort requested; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::session::connection::checkForAbort(rstudio_boost::shared_ptr<rstudio::session::HttpConnection>, rstudio_boost::function<void()>) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionUtils.cpp:137


Nov 2017 09:17:23 [rdesktop] ERROR system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified); OCCURRED AT: virtual void rstudio::core::http::NamedPipeAsyncClient::connectAndWriteRequest() C:/Users/Administrator/rstudio/src/cpp/core/include/core/http/NamedPipeAsyncClient.hpp:84; LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::desktop::NetworkReply::onError(const rstudio::core::Error&) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\desktop\DesktopNetworkReply.cpp:288
```

Comment: use ctrl+click to open Rstudio then you can select the R version or browse R folder

Comment: Thank you the feedback. Everything can be installed on the C drive but in the end Rstudio installs pieces on the network drive. And that's the problem. Rstudio has no troubles finding R itself so selecting the right folders doens't seem to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The support of Rstudio contacted me and gave a link to download a preview release of [rstudio version v1.1.392][1]. It fixed the issue with the changing path of network drive.